# Why did Dolan 37th say, "I'll confess it later"?

Tags: the-last-witch-hunter

In *The Last Witch Hunter (2015)*, while he is taking Ellic to The Witch Council, Dolan 37th says to Kaulder:

> Ellic (to Dolan 37th): You look like a good man, tasty  little thing,
>   you. I never went...
>
> Dolan 37th (to Kaulder): Please don't think less of me.
>
> *Dolan 37th punches Ellic in the stomach*.
>
> Dolan 37th: **I'll confess it later**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is speaking of confessing his sin in the [Catholic sense](http://www.catholic.org/prayers/confession.php), to receive absolution.

Comment: One wonders very, very hard as to why this question have been asked at all... I know RC is not center of the universe, but nevertheless... "New times, new education" or "New education, new times"?